# SocketTimeoutException in android

Tags: android

when I call the method `androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME, Envelope);`
it throws a SocketTimeoutException
here is the code:

```
public SoapObject CallWebService() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException 
    {       
        SoapObject response=null;
        SoapSerializationEnvelope Envelope = GetEnvelope(request);
        Envelope.bodyOut=request;
        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport (URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
        try
           { 
            if(Envelope!=null)
            {
               androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME, Envelope);
            }
               response = (SoapObject) Envelope.getResponse();
               Envelope_class = Envelope;
           }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("AndroidRequest",androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            Log.d("AndroidResponse",androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
            return null;
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Stack Trace:
11-15 16:08:10.767: W/System.err(833): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
11-15 16:08:10.845: W/System.err(833):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:130)
11-15 16:08:10.860: W/System.err(833):  at ApplicationManager.ps.webServices.CallWebService(webServices.java:75)
11-15 16:08:10.875: W/System.err(833):  at ApplicationManager.ps.MainActivity.connect(MainActivity.java:352)
11-15 16:08:10.895: W/System.err(833):  at ApplicationManager.ps.MainActivity.getBoughtApps(MainActivity.java:165)
11-15 16:08:10.925: W/System.err(833):  at ApplicationManager.ps.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:108)
11-15 16:08:10.925: W/System.err(833):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-15 16:08:10.966: W/System.err(833):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-15 16:08:10.966: W/System.err(833):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-15 16:08:10.985: W/System.err(833):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-15 16:08:10.985: W/System.err(833):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-15 16:08:10.999: W/System.err(833):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-15 16:08:10.999: W/System.err(833):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 16:08:11.005: W/System.err(833):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-15 16:08:11.005: W/System.err(833):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-15 16:08:11.005: W/System.err(833):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-15 16:08:11.005: W/System.err(833):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

where is the problem ?

Comment: Could you give us a stack trace?

Comment: @Khalid : is that url valid?

Comment: @Khalid  :check if firewall is blocking the request. Make an exception for that port. Also are you testing on emulator?